# (Python)Localizing variable

Tags: python, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

My goal is to alter dataframe df using my_function then assign the result to dataframe df.
But when I use function the dataframe df which is in the outside of the function is changed.
How could I modify function not to affect the df varable which is outside of funtion?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30]}, index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])


def my_function(df_temp):
    df_temp['A'][0] = 100  # How could I modify not to affect df varable which is outside of funtion
    return df_temp         

   something = my_function(df)
   print(df)   # df is already altered although I didn't assign

# df = my_function(df)
# print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these solutions

1. Using pandas.apply function

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30]}, index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])


def my_function(row):
    row[0] = 100       
    return row


something = df.apply(my_function)
print(something)
```

```sh
A
2021-11-24  100
2021-11-25  20
2021-11-26  30
```

```py
print(df)
```

```sh
A
2021-11-24  10
2021-11-25  20
2021-11-26  30
```

2. Using pandas.copy function

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30]}, index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])

def my_function(df):
    temp_df = df.copy()
    temp_df['A'][0] = 100
    return temp_df


something = my_function(df)
print(something)
```

```sh
A
2021-11-24  100
2021-11-25  20
2021-11-26  30
```

```py
print(df)
```

```sh
A
2021-11-24  10
2021-11-25  20
2021-11-26  30
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are always passed by assignment in Python, so that the DataFrame gets mutated inside of a function. Working on references is preferred as it does not affect the performance.

If you are forced to keep an original object, you can perform the operation by creating a copy manually.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 20, 30]}, index=['2021-11-24', '2021-11-25', '2021-11-26'])

def my_function(df_temp):
    df_temp['A'][0] = 99

dfc = df.copy()
my_function(dfc) # alter the copy

print(df) # unchanged
print(dfc) # altered
```

You can read more about passing variables in the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference